# Ionic 2 Adding Pages, Button to Search page does nothing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I am trying to add a new page to my Ionic app.. I have created the folder 'searchpage' via 'ionic generate page searchpage' in the command line. I have then added...

`import { Searchpage } from '../searchpage/searchpage';`

to the top of 'home.ts' and with this as the @Component underneath...

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authData: AuthData) {

  }

  logMeOut() {
    this.authData.logoutUser().then( () => {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
    });
  }

  searchPage(){
  this.nav.push(Searchpage);
  }

}
```

and then in home.html i add the button...

```html
<button ion-button color="positive" block (click)="searchPage()">
    Search Page
  </button>
```

the button appears but doesn't do anything on click.

Please help what am i doing wrong?

Comment: In your constructor you named the instance of `NavController ` as `navCtrl` but in the `searchPage()` method you're doing `this.nav...`. Change that line for `this.navCtrl.push(Searchpage);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to import the new page in your `app.module.ts` file.
Then add it to the `declarations` and `entryComponents` arrays. See the example below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import {
  Devices,
} from '../providers';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Login } from '../pages/login/login';
import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Login,
    Page1,
    Page2,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Login,
    Page1,
    Page2
  ],
  providers: [
    Devices,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```